# How to order by postcode?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-order-by

I have a small report that needs to be ordered by postcode. How do I do this?

Using `ORDER BY Postcode` returns

`SK1

SK11

SK13

SK2`

**How can I return**

`SK1

SK2

SK11

SK13`

**EDIT**

I should really have added more to the question, I am working with postcodes for the whole of the UK, not just ones starting with SK. So some of these postcodes will start with only 1 letter, some with 2. Also, the second part of the postcode is in the column.

Comment: `Order by (CAST(SUBSTRING(Postcode,3,LEN(Postcode))) As INT)`

Comment: `Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'` If i remove first set of brackets, error returns `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0 2SB' to data type int`

Comment: Try this: `Order by CAST(SUBSTRING(Postcode,3,LEN(Postcode)) AS int)`

Comment: Does the Postcode always start with 'SK' or two characters?

Comment: dataspun's answer is the best you're going to get, but your current design will cause performance problems as data volumes increase

Comment: @WesH Please see edit

Answer (score 1):

Assuming MSSQL, and that your Postcode field follows a consistent pattern of Char(2) + Number, then you could add a computed query column:

```
postcode_num = convert(int,substring(postcode,3,len(postcode)))
```

And then use it instead of Postcode for sorting:

```
order by postcode_num
```

Results as desired:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 columns:
1. a VARCHAR for the first part;
2. a TINYINT for the last (numeric) part.

```
ORDER BY postcode_prefix, postcode_suffix
```

Source: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/order-by-postcode/50042/9

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that the column you are trying to ORDER BY is of type text and not numeric, therefore SQL will perform the ordering you're seeing. Instead, if you want SQL to order it as if it was a number then you would need to substring the "SK" part of the column, cast the number characters to numeric type and then order by that.

This is what @LONG replied to you in the first comment.

Comment: That's a very nice story, but it doesn't exactly provide a solution does it. If you can update the answer with a working solution then it would be a good answer, but as it stands it isn't really a complete answer

Comment: @musefan I think it does provide a solution. I'm saying exactly what is the problem and how to tackle it. Anyway, as I did mention, other user already wrote the code needed to accomplish the thing.

Comment: And what if that comment gets deleted? You can't just post your own answer and say "look at the comments"

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach it is to create a couple of generic functions that will strip the alpha or numeric portions from the string before you sort.

In my example the functions are in the `fn` schema so change this as you require.

```
ORDER BY fn.StripToAlpha(PostCode), fn.StripToNumeric(PostCode)
```

There are plenty of examples of these types of functions around, probably more efficient than the ones I wrote but below is the code to produce the ones I use.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [fn].[StripToAlpha]
(
@inputString nvarchar(4000)
)  
RETURNS varchar(4000)
AS  
BEGIN 

    DECLARE @Counter as int
    DECLARE @strReturnVal varchar(4000)
    DECLARE @Len as int
    DECLARE @ASCII as int

    SET @Counter=0  
    SET @Len=LEN(@inputString)

    SET @strReturnVal = ''

    WHILE @Counter<=@Len
    BEGIN
        SET @Counter = @Counter +1

        SET @ascii= ASCII(SUBSTRING(@inputString,@counter,1))

        IF(@ascii BETWEEN 65 AND 90) OR (@ascii BETWEEN 97 AND 122) 
        BEGIN
            SET @strReturnVal = @strReturnVal + (SUBSTRING(@inputString,@counter,1))
        END
    END

    RETURN @strReturnVal

END
```

and

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [fn].[StripToNumeric]
    (
    @inputString nvarchar(4000)
    )  
RETURNS Float
AS  
BEGIN 

    DECLARE @Counter as int
    DECLARE @strReturnVal varchar(4000)
    DECLARE @ReturnVal Float
    DECLARE @Len as int
    DECLARE @ASCII as int

    SET @Counter=0  
    SET @Len=LEN(@inputString)

    SET @strReturnVal = ''

    IF @inputString IS NULL
        BEGIN
            Return NULL
        END

    -- swap out comma for decimal
    SET @inputString = REPLACE(@inputString, ',', '.')

    IF @Len = 0 OR LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@inputString))) = 0 
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnVal=0
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            WHILE @Counter<=@Len
            BEGIN
                SET @Counter = @Counter +1

                SET @ascii= ASCII(SUBSTRING(@inputString,@counter,1))

                IF(@ascii BETWEEN 48 AND 57) OR (@ascii IN (46,37)) 
                BEGIN
                    SET @strReturnVal = @strReturnVal + (SUBSTRING(@inputString,@counter,1))
                END
            END

            if RIGHT(@strReturnVal,1)='%'
                BEGIN
                    SET @strReturnVal = LEFT(@strReturnVal,len(@strReturnVal)-1)
                    SET @strReturnVal = CAST((CAST(@strReturnVal AS FLOAT)/100) AS nvarchar(4000))
                END

            SET @ReturnVal = ISNULL(@strReturnVal,0)
        END

    RETURN @ReturnVal
END
```

**Notes**

- This will not affect your current use but the StripToNumeric checks is a percentage sign is present and converts to a decimal so it you pass it 25% it will return 0.25.
- This will not work if you use full postcodes such as SK1 1AB as it would sort by SKAB and then 11
- It will work on postcodes with shorter prefixes such M34 (That's Denton if I remember correctly ! :) )

Comment: That certainly is Denton! I am using full postcodes, but just using the first part might be suitable for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify database you use; this is an Oracle example. Hopefully, you'll be able to "convert" it to something else.

The idea is: using **regular expressions** (which seem to be quite handy in such cases), split postcode to two parts: letters and numbers. As `REGEXP_SUBSTR` returns a string, I applied the `TO_NUMBER` function to a "numeric" part of the postcode in order to properly sort it.

```
SQL> with test (postcode) as
  2    (select 'sk1' from dual union
  3     select 'sk11' from dual union
  4     select 'sk13' from dual union
  5     select 'sk2' from dual
  6    )
  7  select postcode
  8  from test
  9  order by regexp_substr(postcode, '^[[:alpha:]]+'),             --> letters
 10           to_number(regexp_substr(postcode, '[[:digit:]]+$'));  --> numbers

POST
----
sk1
sk2
sk11
sk13

SQL>
```

Comment: The question was tagged with "reporting-services" which is SQL Server so...

Comment: Thank you, @musefan. I don't *speak* MS SQL Server so I couldn't *map* "reporting-services" to it. Should have Googled for it, I presume. Anyway, SQL Server does work with regular expressions, doesn't it? Maybe it uses a different syntax, but the general idea should still be OK (at least, I hope so).

Comment: I dunno, I wasn't saying your solution was wrong or right, just pointing out the SQL Server things. If you hover over the tag you don't need to use google ;)